# Chunking a large GraphQL request into smaller requests

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo

I'm using [Apollo React Native](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/integrations/react-native/) client working with a query for which my request body has become too large to use (it's being rejected by our CDN for a request-too-large rule). So, I'm hoping to split/chunk this request into smaller requests and particularly curious if it's possible to do parallelized.

I think this is better illustrated with an example, so we can imagine I'm building a WhatsApp challenger -- WhoseApp -- for which we want users to be able to see who of their contacts have a WhoseApp account upon signup.

For our implementation, we'll take all of the phone numbers stored on our user's device and send them to our GraphQL query `GetPhoneNumberAccountStatus` which accepts an array of phone numbers and which returns an `Account` for each number associated to an account (and nothing for those that are not).

If we send the contacts as one request, we'll have a request body that looks something like this:

```
[
 "+15558675309",
 "+15558675308",
 "+15558675307"
 "+15558675306"
 ...
 // 500+ numbers for some users 
]
```

What's the correct way to split this request into multiple?

I'm curious of both:

1. What's the 'optimal' way to approach this using a sequential approach (e.g., send one group, wait for response, send next group), or
2. Is there a way to do this parallelized (e.g., send all groups at beginning and then receive responses as they arrive)?

I initially figured it might be possible to use `useLazyQuery` and send tranches of ~50 numbers at a time, firing each group and then awaiting the responses but [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6133) for the library makes it clear that that's not the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's readable

```
const promises = [];
const chunkSize = 50;

for (let i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const promise = apollo.query({...dataHere});
    promises.push(promise);
}

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you access the responses when using this client.query(vars) syntax

Comment: From the promise you added in the `promises = []`, index it and access the one you need